# Cant implement correct sorting in javaScript using Array.sort

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of profiles and each array contain profile object that contain "rating" object that contains 2 values:

1. Field named "totalRates" - that hold the value of total sum of rates per profile
2. Array named "rates" - array of objects that contains users id and the value each user rated for this spesific profile.

I want to get the top 3 rated user.
For that i have to map over all profiles and for each profile take the total rate of profile divide by rates.length to get the average and sort.

So what i did is:

```
router.get('/rating/top',async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const profiles=await Profile.find().populate('user',['name','avatar'])

        const ratedProfiles = profiles.map(( profile) =>{
            if(profile.rating.rates.length>0)
            return profile
        })
       
       //'BEFORE SORT'

        const topRated = ratedProfiles.sort((a, b) => (a.rating.totalRates/a.rating.rates.length) - (b.rating.totalRates/b.rating.rates.length));

        //AFTER SORT'
        }
catch(err){
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
}
})
```

the first cell from my output in ratedProfiles:

```
    {
[0]     rating: { totalRates: 5, rates: [Array] },
[0]     skills: [ 'css' ],
[0]     _id: 5f3c3be9ebadb42a189640d5,
[0]     user: {
[0]       _id: 5f3c3bd1ebadb42a189640d4,
[0]       name: 'Yosef Zaltsman',
[0]       avatar: 'http://localhost:5000/public/5f3c3bd1ebadb42a189640d4.jpeg'
[0]     },
[0]     gender: '0',
[0]     status: 'Junior Developer',
[0]     experience: [],
[0]     education: [],
[0]     __v: 1
[0]   },
```

I got same results before and after sorting.
What did i do wrong?

Comment: Could you add example for `ratedProfiles`?

Comment: Yap, see my edit. its just 1 cell from all array , but all the rest looks like this one

Comment: This seems like a perfect problem for a debugger - if you haven't set one up yet this issue could be a good excuse.

Comment: Also I'd be curious if you can reproduce this without the database code being involved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum up all the values of each rating and then divide this sum by the total number of ratings (i.e. calculating the `average` rating). Then you can sort by this average and take the first three values of the resulting array.

Here's a very "verbose" way to do this in order to to show you what's going on:

```js
const ratedProfiles = [
  { rating: { totalRates: 5, rates: [{ value: 10 }, { value: 30 }, { value: 10 }, { value: 10 }, { value: 20 }] } },
  { rating: { totalRates: 1, rates: [{ value: 20 }] } },
  { rating: { totalRates: 2, rates: [{ value: 20 }, { value: 40 }] } },
  { rating: { totalRates: 3, rates: [{ value: 5 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 2 }] } },
  { rating: { totalRates: 4, rates: [{ value: 1 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 8 }] } },
];

const mappedSumRatedProfiles = ratedProfiles.map(profile => {
  const sum = profile.rating.rates.reduce((prev, rate) => rate.value + prev, 0);
  return { rating: { ...profile.rating }, avg: sum / profile.rating.totalRates };
});
mappedSumRatedProfiles.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.avg - a.avg;
});

console.log(mappedSumRatedProfiles.slice(0,3));
```